# Consider the Sorgenfrey plane $\Bbb R^2_\ell$. Show that $L=\{(x,-x) \mid x \in \Bbb R\}$ is closed.

Tags: general-topology

> Consider the Sorgenfrey plane $\Bbb R^2_\ell$. Show that $L=\{(x,-x) \mid x \in \Bbb R\}$ is closed.

This was in Munkres and he just stated that "It is easy to check that $L$ is closed in $\Bbb R^2_\ell$", but I think he meant to say "It is easy for ***me*** to check that $L$ is closed in $\Bbb R^2_\ell$" since if it were easy I wouldn't be posting this question.

Anyway how do I show that this is closed? I know that the basic open sets in $\Bbb R^2_\ell$ are of form $[a,b) \times [c,d)$ and that the intersections of these sets with $L$ give me either singletons or two point sets. This however does not really give me anything to work with in order to prove that $L$ is closed.

Working with the complement $L^c$ also seems not very natural to me as I don't know how I can show it's open. If $(x,y) \in L^c$ I don't know how to find an open set containing these two points. I think there is four cases to be considered here?

Answer (score 0):

We will show that $L^c$ is open. Let $p=(x, y) \notin L$. Then either $y<-x$ (the point is "below" $L$), or $y>-x$.

In the first case, let $r=(-x-y)/2>0$, and consider the open set $U=[x, x+r) \times [y, y+r)$. It is clear that $p \in U$. If $(t, -t) \in U$, then $x \leq t<x+r$ and $y \leq -t < y+r$, so
$$ y+r>-t > -x-r. $$
This contradicts the choice of $t$. (It is worth drawing a picture here: we are picking a square that "avoids" the line $L$.)

In the second case (i.e. $y>-x$) we pick $U=[x, x+1) \times [y, y+1)$. (In the picture, here the square can be taken as large as we want.) In fact, if $(t, -t) \in U$, then
$$ x\leq t < x+1, \quad y \leq -t <y+1 \implies y \leq -t \leq -x, $$
a contradiction.

It follows that $L^c$ is open, hence $L$ is closed. It is worth comparing this to the fact that $L$ is closed in the usual topology in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the argument is pretty similar (e.g. if you fix a metric, it reduces to a triangle inequality, which is sort of what we did in the first part).